# Is it possible to provide secret to docker run?

Tags: docker

I am just wondering whether it's possible to provide docker secret created from any file to docker run as an argument, or is it possible to mount docker secret during docker run.
I know it's possible using docker service where we can specify --secret while creating secret but I didn't see such option for docker run.

Comment: I guess you have to run in swarm mode to have this feature available.

Comment: secrets can be mounted to a docker service only not directly to a container as @Henry says. And it is quit easy to initialize a swarm even on a single host.

Answer (score 7):

The docker secrets functionality is implemented only in swarm mode. You can make a single node swarm cluster very easily (`docker swarm init`) and run your container as a service. Some will simply mount a file containing the secret for one off containers as a single file read only host volume. e.g.:

```
docker run -v "$(pwd)/your_secret.txt:/run/secrets/your_secret.txt:ro" image_name
```

This has less security than a swarm mode secret, but the real value of swarm secrets are in multi-node clusters where you don't want to deploy and manage a directory of sensitive data on worker nodes.

Answer (score 0):

As for docker-compose v3.1 file, it's possible to use docker secrets with docker-compose. https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#secrets

Comment: The v3 syntax is for swarm mode.